# httplib2 giving internal server error 500 with proxy

Tags: python, proxy, socks, httplib2

Following is the code and error it throws. It works fine without the proxy `http = httplib2.Http()` .

When I try the same http proxy in Firefox, it works fine.

Any pointers are highly appreciated!

Usage :

```
http = httplib2.Http(proxy_info = httplib2.ProxyInfo(socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP, '68.48.25.158', 25681))

main_url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com'
response, content = http.request(main_url, 'GET')
```

Error :

```
  File "testproxy.py", line 17, in <module>
    response, content = http.request(main_url, 'GET')
  File "/home/kk/bin/pythonlib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1129, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/home/kk/bin/pythonlib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 901, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/home/kk/bin/pythonlib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 862, in _conn_request
    conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 866, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 889, in _send_request
    self.endheaders()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 860, in endheaders
    self._send_output()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 732, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/httplib.py", line 699, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/kk/bin/pythonlib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 740, in connect
    self.sock.connect(sa)
  File "/home/kk/bin/pythonlib/socks.py", line 383, in connect
    self.__negotiatehttp(destpair[0],destpair[1])
  File "/home/kk/bin/pythonlib/socks.py", line 349, in __negotiatehttp
    raise HTTPError((statuscode,statusline[2]))
socks.HTTPError: (500, 'Internal Server Error')
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the proxy isn't transparent. I don't know too much about this, but evidently a transparent proxy enables the server to see you're using a proxy, and perhaps even access your IP. Some websites will definitely shut down any requests that appear to originate from a proxy (for fear of bots). That may mean either throwing a fake internal server error or actually encountering an error. For me, using an anonymous proxy has always solved that problem. Since you said it works without the proxy, I would start there.

Comment: Thank you..I was using an anonymous proxy. It worked fine when I used it with Firefox but not via httplib2..

Comment: Hmm, so it worked when you configged FF to use the proxy, buy failed when you used hhtplib2?. Now my suspicion is that your request was denied because it lacked the requisite spoofing of the user-agent header. The code snippet above doesn't include anything to suggest the user-agent was spoofed. That could also result in a 550 error. However htt2lib requires, you to do it <http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/wiki/Examples>, set it to something like `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.9) Gecko/20100401 Ubuntu/9.10 (karmic) Firefox/3.5.9` That'll probably do it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the [SOCKS client library](http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/) installed and available to your code? The proxy support only works if the SOCKS library is installed.

Comment: I put socks.py at /home/kk/bin/pythonlib/socks.py .. Still no go.. Thanks!